# Was my comment inappropriate?

Tags: discussion

I don’t have enough reputation to vote to close or migrate questions, so instead I commented on [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745327/how-to-transform-circle-from-cartesian-to-polar-coordinates) and wrote “This question is about math, not physics.” The comment was deleted. Was it wrong, rude, or otherwise inappropriate for me to write this comment?

Comment: I don't see any deleted comment from you on that question, nor do you have a deleted comment like that on any other question.

Comment: I understand 100% of all physics that don't require math. Which is about as useless as your comment was.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The user posted essentially the same question twice, presumably by accident, then (correctly) deleted one of them.  Your comment was on [the other](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745315/polar-coordinates), nearly-identical question.  (However, you will not currently be able to see anything by following that link—since you have to have 10k reputation to see deleted questions.)